# JS Выбор тега html

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная, в которой хранится html код: `<p><img src="/"></p>`
Как из этого выбрать только `<img>` и записать в отдельную переменную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну есть несколько способов получить из документа:

1. Получить по ID:

html

```
img src="/" id ="UnicImgID">
```

js

```
let img = document.getElementByID("UnicImgID");
```

2. Через querySelector:

```
let img = document.querySelector("img");
```

Ну, а если надо из переменной, то можно попробовать replace:

```
let img = str.replace("/<p>", "");
```

Comment: Можно ли из переменной, убрать всё вместе с текстом кроме <img>? а не заменять всё по отдельности

Comment: @CrossCheat То есть? Вам надо атрибут src из img получить?

Answer (score 0):

```
'<p><img src="/"></p>'.replace(/<p>(.*)<\/p>/, '$1')
```

[Про "$1"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n)